# How to make HTTPS GET call with certificate(.pem file and .key file) in Rest-Assured java

Tags: rest, ssl-certificate, rest-assured

How to make HTTPS GET call with certificate(.pem file and .key file)  in Rest-Assured java

tried with keystore , but no luck since I need to bypass SSL certificate validation with pem file and key file.
I have a .crt file and a .key file which I have to send with my rest call using Rest assured java. Everywhere I am finding answers where it has been suggested to turn those files into a single .pfx file but the problem is that the server does not accept pfx. It accepts .pem and .key files. Is it really possible to send a .pem file along with a get call using Restassured?I tried to use the following code but the response always says "connection denied". Thanks in advance for any kind of help. Need to automate api services with  my ssl certificate.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.